# How to fix "Some URLs listed in this Sitemap have a high response time" from Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

Google Search Console says:

> Some URLs listed in this Sitemap have a high response time. This may indicate a problem with your server or with the content of the page

I submitted this site in  Google Search Console along with the sitemap 2 months ago.  These pages were created more than 2 months ago.  Why would Google find these problems so recently?

How do I fix it?

Comment: The duplicate question doesn't directly address why you are getting these messages recently:  Googlebot crawls your site all the time,  and it has recently found pages on your site that are listed in your sitemap but which take too much time to load.